# Dynamodb filterExpression with multiple condition is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a **`dynamodb`** query in nodejs as follows. **`I have a matching record`** but its not returning any values. Any idea to resolve the problem?

```
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "ap-south-1" });
var userParams = {
        TableName: "aa-users",
        FilterExpression: '#email = :emailval AND #postProfileOTP = :otpval',
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              "#email": "email",
              "#postProfileOTP": "postProfileOTP"
          },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":emailval": email,
            ":otpval": otp
        }
    };
    docClient.scan(userParams, function (err, data) {
         console.log(data.Count) // not getting the result count
         if(data.Count > 0){
          res.status(200).json({ "status": 1, "data": data.Items })
         }
    })
```

Instead am getting the error as follows:

> 2020-01-24T11:56:20.554Z  ee0fd306-6bd5-4cf0-957e-732b08c6b0e3    ERROR   Uncaught
>   Exception  {
>       "errorType": "TypeError",
>       "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'Count' of null",
>       "code": "TypeError",
>       "message": "Cannot read property 'Count' of null",
>       "time": "2020-01-24T11:56:20.554Z",
>       "stack": [
>           "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Count' of null",
>           "    at Response. (/var/task/handler.js:351:18)",
>           "    at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:364:18)",
>           "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
>           "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
>           "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
>           "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
>           "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
>           "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
>           "    at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
>           "    at Request. (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)"
>       ] }

Answer (score 2):

It looks like AWS is returning an err rather than results/data. When you receive a callback that has an "err" parameter as the first argument, you should always check that this is not set before continuing. Eg:

```
if (err) {
   console.error(err)
   // recover in some way, or kill process
   process.exit(1)
}
```

By doing this, the error being returned from AWS will be logged to the console, and you'll have a much better idea of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

simply log out the error thrown by dynamoDb.
We will know the reason.

Like this

`

```
docClient.scan(userParams, function (err, data) {
      if(err) console.log(err)
         if(data.Count > 0){
          res.status(200).json({ "status": 1, "data": data.Items })
         }
```

`

Comment: I logged the error, and now am getting no result. But i have a matching record. **Count** error gone now.

Comment: What are you getting in error?  would you please paste that in your question by editing that

Comment: Sorry actually the mistake was i was checking a number field (**otp**) as string. It was needed to convert to in integer type before the conditional check. Thats why it didn't returned any result. Thanks btw. It worked! :)